# Send button auto set recipient

Tags: facebook, button, send

Is there a way to set a recipient when clicked on the share button without the user inputing him.

The idea is to show a list of FB friends that might be interested in the site. And next to each user will be a send button. When the button is clicked its all filled in so the user just needs to click post.

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

just add this:

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          to:'#frinds id#',

          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
      });
```

Comment: Is it required to pass 'link' parameter ? I don't want to pass it.